# Transfer code from sheet/module to UserForm in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a small simulation and would now like to transfer it completely into a UserForm. Unfortunately, it does not work as I thought and the exchange of e.g. sheet/sheets to UserForm1 does not work that easily.

Example:

in Sheet:

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    PlayStopMacro = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton3.BackColor = vbRed
    Else
    PlayStopMacro = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton3.BackColor = vbGreen
    next_moment1
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "StopMacro1"
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    PlayStopMacro = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton4.BackColor = vbRed
    Else
    PlayStopMacro = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton4.BackColor = vbGreen
    next_moment2
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "StopMacro2"
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    PlayStopMacro = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton5.BackColor = vbRed
    Else
    PlayStopMacro = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton5.BackColor = vbGreen
    next_moment3
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:45"), "StopMacro3"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

in Module:

```
Public PlayStopMacro As Boolean

Sub next_moment1()
If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.BackColor <> RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment1"
End If

End Sub

Sub StopMacro1()
PlayStopMacro = False
Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton3.BackColor = RGB(238, 238, 238)
Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub

Sub next_moment2()
If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.BackColor <> RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment2"
End If

End Sub

Sub StopMacro2()
PlayStopMacro = False
Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton4.BackColor = RGB(238, 238, 238)
Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

End Sub

Sub next_moment3()
If PlayStopMacro = True Then
    If Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.BackColor <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.Value = "Achtung"
    Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.Value = "Auto nähert sich von hinten"
    End If
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment3"
End If

End Sub

Sub StopMacro3()
PlayStopMacro = False
Sheets("Sheet1").CommandButton5.BackColor = RGB(238, 238, 238)
Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.Value = ""
Sheets("Sheet1").TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
End Sub
```

I am glad if someone has an interesting link to this topic, because my search hasn't found anything usefull/ working yet. Its just a small part from the code but i guess i get it work as soon as i know the method. Thank you

Comment: In a userform  you would use `Me.CommandButton3.BackColor` for example.  Aside from that it's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: Do you receive  any error? If yes, in which procedure, which line and which error? If not, what problem does the migrated code have?

Comment: Ok thank you, got it. It could be so simple, damn.